# Observable creates additional observable in onResume

Tags: android, location, observable, rx-java2

I created Observable on location changes. But the problem is when app came back from background to foreground -> here another observable is created. 
The process looks like this:
in onCreate() method I create observable on location. When app goes to background location updates works fine. But when app comes back to foreground an observable creates another observation on location and I've got additional data (another observable on location). To sum up, every time when an app comes back from background to foreground observable creates another observable which is not needed. In onResume() I don't have any implementation.

Does somebody have some idea how to resolve this challenge and ommit additional observables? Just the first one is needed.

Below I show snippet of my code in onCreate:

```
            .flatMap(new Function<LocationSettingsResult, Observable<Location>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Location> apply(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                    }
                    LogUtil.i(TAG, "location request: " + lastKnownLocationObservable.toString());
                    return locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(locationRequest);
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

LogCat:

```
I/MainActivity: 46.000000 16.000000
I/MainActivity: 46.000000 16.000000 -> second observable which is not needed.
```

Comment: Are you disposing the old subscription in `onDestroy`?

Comment: I tried using: "lastKnownLocationObservable.doOnDispose(this::onDestroy); " -> but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873048/q-rxjava-how-the-clear-compositedisposable-method-work-internally) is an example how flows are started and disposed.

Comment: @akarnokd For example I disposed subscription in onPause and it was unsubscipted. But it should work also in onStop and onPause. When I unsubscibe -> of course, updates were stopped. The question is where should I put this disposable? When I put it in onResume it also won't to work because it's called immediately after onCreate.

Comment: I don't understand. Please provide a minimal Activity that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Finally I managed with it. I created a boolean variable which detect if onResume method was called. Also in onResume I call disposable but when activity is launched at first time and onResume is called first time those disposable doesn't activate. But when onResume is called again those disposable is activated. That's my workaround solution. However, thank you for your help.